# Regarding the smallest $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbf{R}$ containing $\mathcal{A}=\{(0,1), (0,\infty)\}$.

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

I am currently having a fundamental misunderstanding regarding $\sigma$-algebras.  In particular, I am a bit confused about a specific example of the "smallest" $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbf{R}$ that contains the set of subsets $\mathcal{A}=\{(0,1), (0,\infty)\}$.  According to my text, the smallest $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbf{R}$ that contains $\mathcal{A}$ is given by $$\mathcal{S}=\{\emptyset, (0,1), (0,\infty), (-\infty,0]\cup[1,\infty), (-\infty,0], [1,\infty), (-\infty,1), \mathbf{R}\}.$$

My question here is somewhat of a silly notational one regarding all the sets at play here.  When I think of $\mathcal{S}$ containing $\mathcal{A}$, I think that the entire set $\{(0,1),(0,\infty)\}$ should be explicitly found within $\mathcal{S}$, i.e. $\mathcal{S}=\{\{(0,1),(0,\infty)\}, ...\}$.  Instead, all I see in $\mathcal{S}$ are the individual *elements* of $\mathcal{A}$, and not $\mathcal{A}$ itself, if that makes sense.

Honestly I have no idea how people study this stuff, because it's the little things like this that just stop me dead in my tracks!  Can anybody explain where I am going wrong here?

Thanks as always!

Comment: "$S$ contains $A$" means $A\subset S$, **not** $A\in S$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown And that answers my question right there.

Comment: Contains is ambiguish.